# when Install the npm, found 12 high severity vulnerabilities

Tags: npm

In angular 8, when I have install the npm then found 12 high severity vulnerabilities.

Version:-

```
Angular CLI: 8.0.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.0.1
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.800.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.800.3
@angular-devkit/core              8.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.0.3
@angular/cli                      8.0.3
@angular/fire                     5.2.1
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.26
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  8.0.3
@schematics/angular               8.0.3
@schematics/update                0.800.3
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.4.5
webpack                           4.30.0
```

When I run the command npm audit then show

```
     === npm audit security report ===                        


                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > fstream            

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar > fstream      

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libnpm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > fstream             

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libnpm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar > fstream       

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > node-gyp > fstream                                      

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > node-gyp > tar > fstream                                

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > fstream                      

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         fstream                                                       

  Patched in      >=1.0.12                                                      

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar > fstream                

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/886                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         tar                                                           

  Patched in      >=2.2.2 <3.0.0 || >=4.4.2                                     

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libcipm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         tar                                                           

  Patched in      >=2.2.2 <3.0.0 || >=4.4.2                                     

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > libnpm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                 

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         tar                                                           

  Patched in      >=2.2.2 <3.0.0 || >=4.4.2                                     

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > node-gyp > tar                                          

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/803                              


  High            Arbitrary File Overwrite                                      

  Package         tar                                                           

  Patched in      >=2.2.2 <3.0.0 || >=4.4.2                                     

  Dependency of   npm                                                           

  Path            npm > npm-lifecycle > node-gyp > tar                          

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/803
```

found 12 high severity vulnerabilities in 31845 scanned packages
  12 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.

I want to found 0 severity vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `package.json` file and search the `npm` then remove `npm version` line (like  `"npm": "^6.9.0"`) from the `package.json` file.

Then Delete the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file from the project.

Then install the `npm` using command `npm install`.

Now you should see `0` vulnerabilities.

Comment: new angular project (12.2.0) on Node.js v14.18.0 (with npm 6.14.15) has **18 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 12 high)**. Upgrading npm to 8.0.0, removing node_modules and package-lock.json and executing npm install results in **25 vulnerabilities (6 moderate, 19 high)**. So your solution may be a solution in the past, but does not work now.

Comment: I have 12 vulnerabilities and several warnings for gulp and gulp-watch. The method above did not solve it.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an angular-related question. `npm` reports that some packages have known security issues.

You can try to run `npm audit fix` to let the dependency be upgraded to a known vulnerable one (if any), otherwise, you have to wait for the package maintainer to fix those issues.

Keep in mind that security vulnerabilities, although very important, are reported also for development packages, which, may not end up in your production system.

If upgrading the dependencies or (changing them) does not solve, you can't do anything on your own.